# Calculate time difference in c# windows phone 7

Tags: c#

I am trying to **calculate the time difference between 2 time** and put the result into a text block.

For example,

Start time: 9:45 AM

End start: 5:15 PM

How can i **calulate the time difference** between it?

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), "hh:mm tt", new DateTimeFormatInfo());

```
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(timePicker1.ValueString, "hh:mm tt", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
```

TimeSpan ts1 = dt2.Subtract(dt1);

Comment: check with this http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/217151-Time-difference-c.aspx

Comment: i tried that way but dont really get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time "11:12 PM" you should use format "h:mm tt". So, you parse two time strings and make [Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx) or just (dateTime1 - dateTime2).

Comment: i amended my question with the code. Still having the same problem

Comment: You should use "hh:mm tt" instead of "hh:mm:tt".

Comment: Changed. Still the same error. Not sure what is wrong with it

Comment: dt2 time is get from a time picker

Comment: May be problem in value of timePicker1.ValueString. Has it correct time format or something such "13:25 AM"? I've tried to run my code and it works. Try to use your code without timePicker1.ValueString.

Comment: @bentan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2124/discussion-between-rover-and-ben-tan)

Comment: Oh, sorry, try to use "h:mm tt" format. But I don't know why it works. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("22:22:22", "HH:mm:ss", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact("11:11:11", "HH:mm:ss", new DateTimeFormatInfo());
TimeSpan ts1 = dt1.Subtract(dt2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare and get DateTime values
    DateTime StartDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    DateTime EndDate = System.DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Find time difference between two dates
    TimeSpan TimeDifference = StartDate - EndDate;

    // Write difference in hours and minutes
    Response.Write("Time difference between server time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) is " +
        TimeDifference.Hours.ToString() + " hours ");
    if (TimeDifference.Minutes != 0)
        Response.Write(" and " + TimeDifference.Minutes.ToString() + " minutes.");

}
```

or try

```
    /* Read the initial time. */
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(startTime);

/* Do something that takes up some time. For example sleep for 1.7 seconds. */
Thread.Sleep(1700);

/* Read the end time. */
DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(stopTime);

/* Compute the duration between the initial and the end time. 
 * Print out the number of elapsed hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. */
TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
Console.WriteLine("hours:" + duration.Hours);
Console.WriteLine("minutes:" + duration.Minutes);
Console.WriteLine("seconds:" + duration.Seconds);
Console.WriteLine("milliseconds:" + duration.Milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method suggested by O.D. is what I use in my app that uses a time difference.  I then use the method ng_ducnghia suggests to separate units of time (hours, min, sec - I don't need millisec for my purpose).